# Flutter 3.13.7 not working with Xcode 15 and iOS 17

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, dart

I updated my project to Flutter 3.13.7, Xcode 15.0 and iOS 17 but I can not run it anymore.

It is always failing with:

> Error (Xcode): Framework not found Protobuf
>
> Error (Xcode): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
> invocation)
>
> Could not build the application for the simulator. Error launching
> application on iPhone 15 Pro Max.

Although the framwork is different, sometimes it's `Protobuf` but can also be `flutter_image_compress`, I don't think it's a package-issue.

I cleaned everything, deintegrated/installed/updated pod, deleted all cached/derived data.

I also tried adding -ld64 “Other linker flags”, mentioned [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/731089). Also not working.

Couldn't find any more on this. Happy for every help! Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: It mean you updated macOS to sonoma and then you had to updated xcode and related tools?

Comment: @KasunHasanga updated eveything, but the problem is not with Sonoma. Had the same issue on another Mac, without the Sonoma update.

Comment: In android release and on android emulators are working?

Comment: yes. Everything is working fine with Android.

Answer (score 1):

Delete next two lines:

- -framework
- "protobuf"

From "Other Linker Flags" property in Targets->Runner->Build Settings